# How to get option from child product(simple) in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am working in magento 2.2.5.

I need to get all option from child sku.

**For example :**

> I have sku `MH02-L-Purple` I need to get that selected option from this
>   sku.

**Result should be :**

Color: Purple

Size : L

Comment: please specify when you want to get this data? on backend or front?